# Adding browser that works in a textbox?

Tags: html, css

What would the code be to have a specific url running in a browser in a textbox of my site?I want that to be in html for use in blogspot.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean by iframe?

```html
<iframe src="http://www.google.com"></iframe>
```

Comment: Is that a question or an answer?

Comment: Let me explain what I mean. There is a website with a webtv channel but I cannot get the code to place it to my site.So I think that if I place in a box the browser with the specific address of the webtv, I could then add it to my blog to run.

Answer (score 0):

To do what you are asking, use an iframe to load the page, the height and width of the iframe can be set the same way any html tag's width and height are set. Just use width and height attributes in the tag such as I have displayed.

It is possible for web developers to add code to deny their pages being run in an iframe, if this is the case for your scenario, you cannot embed without an embed script from the site owner

```html
<iframe src="http://www.stackoverflow.com" width="500px" height="250px"></iframe>
```